# Graying out inactive preprocessor directives in IAR Embedded Workbench

Tags: syntax-highlighting, iar, preprocessor-directive

Is there a way I can have IAR Embedded Workbench grey out inactive blocks of code within preprocessor conditions?

E.g.

```
#ifdef TEST
    some code
#endif
```

So if macro TEST is not defined the "some code" part is somehow greyed out?

Comment: I have been asking myself the same thing. Maybe there is a plugin or extension, because there's nothing int he menus.

Comment: It is not possible as far as I know, the IDE is quite limited, but you may want to have a look and try with Atmel Studio 6.2.

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been implemented at some point in the later versions of the IAR IDE for Arm.

The checkbox to enable/disable it can be found under `Tools`-`IDE Options`-`Editor`-`[x] Show Inactive code`.

I am using it since 9.10 as well as the official IAR extension for VScode.

Comment: ... yes it does exist - as of 9.20.4 it uses the same color as "C++ comments" (green in my case)... I would prefer "grey background" or having ability to select a unique color (i would pick grey).

Comment: @Frederick I am on 9.40.1 mostly with VSCode, CMake Tools and the IAR Debug extension (pretty much similar to [this](https://github.com/IARSystems/iar-vscode-cmake) setup). It seems the normal IDE only offers foreground color selector for individual elements (such as comments) as you previously mentioned.  However, the only option available for background color selection is global. It might change in the future.